# Default Request Header of IOS WKWebview and RN-Webivew

Tags: ios, wkwebview, react-native-webview

I have trouble with RN-webview when rendering my page on IOS machines in China.

For the details,

1. My page(server) is in Korea and clients are in China.
2. When trying to access page via browser app and pure swift WKWebview app, my page can be rendered.
3. When trying to access page via RN-Webview, can't render my page.
   (NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005. The network connection was lost.)

So, I think, there are some difference between RN-Webview and WKWebview so they makes this error.

For the first step, I'm going to check what kind of default values are set in request header of WKWebview.

It is because my page is failed with -1005 error which is about connection.
When google this issue, many people said it can be about header issue.

In the nutshell, where can I check the default values of WKWebview and RN-Webivew request headers?